# Asynchronous consumption of InputStream

Tags: java, media-player, inputstream

I want to play streaming media, received from a internet service. The media player works fine, but is sometimes interrupted due to poor download rate.
On receiving of media data I run a thread that does decoding and other manipulations, the abstract code looks like that:

```
private void startConsuming(final InputStream input) {
    consumingThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            runConsumingThread(input);
        }
    };
    consumingThread.start();
}
```

My idea is to calculate the buffer size needed to prevent interruption, and to start media playback once the buffer is filled (or, of cause, if the stream ends).

```
private void startConsuming(final InputStream input) {
    consumingThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            runConsumingThread(input);
        }
    };
    Thread fillBufferThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(input.available() < RECEIVING_BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES) {
                    log.debug("available bytes: " + input.available());
                    sleep(20);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // ignore
            }
            consumingThread.start();
        }
    };
    fillBufferThread.start();
}
```

In debug I get continuously "available bytes: 0" while stream arrives and does not break the while loop. I recognized already, that EOFException will of cause not occur, since I do not read from InputStream.
How can I handle this? I thought that input.available() would increase on data arrival.
Why can runConsumingThread(input) work correctly in nearly the same manner, but my while loop in fillBufferThread does not?

**EDIT:** Following code nearly works (except that it wrongly consumes the input stream, which is then not played in consumingThread, but that will be easy to solve), but there must be a smarter solution.

```
[...]
    Thread fillBufferThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            final DataInputStream dataInput = new DataInputStream(input);
            try {
                int bufferSize = 0;
                byte[] localBuffer = new byte[RECEIVING_BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES];
                while(bufferSize < RECEIVING_BUFFER_SIZE_BYTES) {
                    int len = dataInput.readInt();
                    if(len > localBuffer.length){
                        if (D) log.debug("increasing buffer length: " + len);
                        localBuffer = new byte[len];
                    }
                    bufferSize += len;
                    log.debug("available bytes: " + bufferSize);
                    dataInput.readFully(localBuffer, 0, len);
                }
            consumingThread.start();
        }
    };
[...]
```

It can't be efficient to read from stream until I know, that I have it filled with a number of bytes, or is it?

Comment: What kind of InputStream do you use? And where does it come from? Note that the base implementation of InputStream will always return 0. Additionally, if your player is consuming the stream faster than the download rate, only waiting for an initial buffer may not help. Depending on its size and the duration of streaming it will be exhausted and the player will have to deal with the reduced download rate.

Comment: @Pyranja Streaming source can vary: receiving from server on LAN or WAN (even mobile network) or from file. Well, I noticed that available() always returns 0 if getting stream from server (and, aditionally, I always get 1071 (?!) when reading from file...), but what is my alternative (without consuming it to find out)? After initial buffer is filled, I can prevent interruption with different methods, but I must ensure to have enough buffer (= time) to use these methods.

Comment: You could actually consume it, but keep the data in a buffer (e.g. a `byte[]`) that is big enough to give you the time needed. Then you write your own InputStream implementation that reads from the filled buffer and switches to the real stream after the buffer is exhausted. As long as the buffer need not be excessively large that should work.

Comment: @Pyranja As you can see, I started to implement exactly this, and edited my question acordingly. ;) (Buffersize is somewhere in the range from 640 to 16000, so fine for that purpose.)

Comment: As streams may be infinite and transport modes vary, I am not aware of any reliable way to retrieve or estimate the size of a generic InputStream apart from consuming it.

Comment: @Pyranja Since I only need the information, how many bytes arrived until "now", I thought there must be any basic implementation of a counter holding the information, how many bytes already streamed.

Comment: [guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CountingInputStream.html) has a counting stream and implementing one yourself is straight forward.

Comment: @Pyranja Ahhh, yes Sir. This is of cause the way: Implementing a CountingInputStream inheriting from InputStream and let the stream pass the CountingInputStream. If you suggest that as an answer, I will mark it as accepted!